# Unknown div adding length to page if page is shorter than window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a *sticky footer* on my site. Not a "sticks to the bottom of the window no matter how much you scroll" stickyfooter, but a "No matter how long the page, the footer will go at the bottom of your window, provided you scroll all the way down" sticky footer.

I have tried implementing 4-5 different versions from around the web, but I have run into a problem:

Every time I have a page that is **less than** the height of the user's browser, the page will add in around 100px after the content, before the footer, and then you will see your page, a big blank space, and then if you scroll down, the footer.

Here is a page that is having the problem: https://elcheapohost.com/contact

So here is a shortened version of the code:

```
<head>...snip...</head>
<div id="wrap">Content Here</div>
</div><!-- /wrap--><div id="foot">
<footer>
        <div class=" copyright">&copy; Copyright <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <a href="http://www.joshuapedroza.com">Joshua Pedroza</a>. All Rights Reserved. <a href="/tos">Terms of Service</a>.</div>
</footer><!-- End  footer  --></div> <!-- /foot -->
```

And the css:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;/* needed to base 100% height on something known*/
}
#wrap {
    margin:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    padding-top:-48px;/*footer height - this drags the outer 40px up through the top of the monitor */

}
* html #wrap {
    height:100%
}
#foot {/* footer now sits at bottom of window*/
    padding-top: 35px;
    margin:auto;
    height:48px;/* must match negative margin of #wrap */
    clear:both;
}
/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {/* thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec)*/
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}
#wrap:after {/* thank you Erik J - instead of using display table for ie8*/
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    height:1%;
    content:" ";
}
```

I am not sure if this is a twitter bootstrap issue, since I have had issues with this same bug in the past. Has anyone else encountered it?

Example of page:
Content longer: http://gyazo.com/a03348451474ad62e3250273cfe474de
Content shorter: http://gyazo.com/8221af4593dd58f98cedebd5670e4e8a (No matter how short the page is, it will always add in that scroll bar)

Comment: Do you have the CSS for the footer?

Comment: Yes, but if you do an element inspect, it seems that the space is added to the wrap div, before the footer.

Comment: Oh. Can you settle footer margin to bottom to lock it down and then allow the main content to do its thing?

Comment: @SteveGreen Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Remove from

`padding-top:35px`

from  /#foot

in stick_footer.css

and

`margin-top:35px`

from footer

in styles.css

There will no longer be a space between the footer and the bottom of the content.
If this was not your answer let me know and I can dig a little deeper.

Comment: Nope, no dice :( Still have that random space added. (This time, only on pages not long enough. On long pages, there is none at all) I want to have a 35px space between the start of the footer and the end of the content, or a larger space if there is less content on a page, but for some reason, when there is not enough content, it adds extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a screenshot and label the page with the url so I can see it.

Edit: I'm not seeing this occurring on my computer. I've checked the page in the screenshot against all browsers I have. Which browser are you using?